# Array elements representation in data table

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a data set where some of the field values are arrays and I'd like to use crossfilter and d3.js or dc.js to display this data table.
I have tried doing this with this code:

```
var data = [
{"Name":"ajay","interests":[{"games":"vally"},{ "games":"cricket"}]},
]
var assetDataCF = crossfilter(data );
var dimByHostName = assetDataCF.dimension(function(d){return d.Name; });

var apSecAdvConfig = dc.dataTable('#apSecAdvConfig');
        apSecAdvConfig
            .dimension(dimByHostName)
            .group(function(d){ return "" })
            .transitionDuration(1000)
            .columns([ 
                  function(d) { return d.Name;},
                  function(d) { var s=d.interests,
                                  a=[];
                        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++)
                        {
                             a.push(d.s[i].games);

                        } return a;}
                 }];
```

It displays the table as follows:

```
-------------------------------
name   ---   games
-----------------------------
 ajay   ---   vally,cricket
------------------------------
```

...but I want the result to be:

---

```
   name   ---   games
 ------------------------
   ajay   ---   vally
  -----------------------
   ajay   ----   cricket
  ------------------------
**********************************************
```

Anyone has any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

We can change the dataset

```
    var data = [
    {"Name":"ajay","interests":[{"games":"vally"},{ "games":"cricket"}]},
    {"Name":"cyril","interests":[{"games":"football"}]},
    ];
var newData = [];
data.forEach(function (person) {
    person.interests.forEach(function (interest) {
        newData.push({
            Name: person.Name,
            interest: interest.games
        })
    })
})
```

The above function will make the newdataset like this:

```
    [{"Name":"ajay","interest":"vally"},
{"Name":"ajay","interest":"cricket"},
{"Name":"cyril","interest":"football"}]
```

Post this your code can work on the newData set created above
something like this:

```
var assetDataCF = crossfilter(newData );
//oldcode...
```

Comment: This is correct. Worth noting that if you don't want this particular behavior in the data table but instead want this kind of behavior in one of the other dc.js charts, you have the option to use Crossfilter's groupAll behavior to include a single record in multiple groups.